# Dogecoin не собирается на Debian ни в какую... поможите, люди!

Tags: debian, openssl, makefile, bitcoin

litecoin и bitcoin собрались... ну на то они и 1-ый и 2-ой.

Далее, пытаюсь поставить doge:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin.git
$ cd dogecoin
$ sh autogen.sh
$ time ./configure --with-incompatible-bdb
```

и конфигуре падает с криками

```
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_chrono... yes
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... yes
checking for dynamic linked boost test... yes
checking for SSL... yes
checking for CRYPTO... yes
checking for RAND_egd in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: Detected LibreSSL: This is NOT supported, and may break consensus compatibility!
```

хотя LibreSSL в памине нет...

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
```

Далее, пробовал другие монетки, такие как Infinitycoin... и они тоже не собираются, и крик там идёт на `BN_init()`. Оказалось, что *deprecated* всякие такие вызовы в новом openssl... Видимо они в сторону Libre ростут... И там и сям Тео правит так и так...

Ну ладно, тут:

https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/depends/packages/openssl.mk

я узнал, что

> $(package)_version=1.0.1l

Скачал: https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.1/openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz

Собрал && Поставил.

```
$ ls -latr /usr/src/coins/openssldir/
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:23 man
drwxrwxrwx 13 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:25 private
drwxr-xr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:25 include
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:25 certs
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 10835 Dec  9 19:26 openssl.cnf
drwxr-xr-x  9 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:26 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:26 misc
drwxr-xr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Dec  9 19:26 lib

$ find  /usr/src/coins/openssldir/ | wc
   1336    1336   71777
```

Кормлю это всё *dogecoin-овскому* `./configure`:

```
$ CFLAGS+=" -I/usr/src/coins/openssldir/include/openssl" CPPFLAGS+=" -I/usr/src/coins/openssldir/include/openssl" LDFLAGS+=" -L/usr/src/coins/openssldir/lib"; time ./configure --with-incompatible-bdb
```

та же самая ошибка.

Как только я ему не подавал, и через `--openssldir=`, и флаги все подряд выставлял... Не видет он `non-standard` openssl. А на текущую версию

```
$ /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```

кричит что это Libre....

Куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В соответствии с [openssl wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:BN_new(3)):

> BN_init() is no longer available as of OpenSSL 1.1.0. It was used to
>   initialize an existing uninitialized BIGNUM. Typically this would be
>   done as follows:

Видимо, Сатоши Накамото не ведал, что такое может произойти. Использовав в первых версиях *Bitcoin* конструктор *BN_init()*, он обрёк тысячи *"вилок"* биткоина на *"устаревание"*...

Собрать с последней библиотекой *libssl-dev* подавляющее количество монет просто нельзя.

На [форумах](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1374377.msg13987713) можно найти как избавится от ошибки/проверки `error: Detected LibreSSL`. Достаточно в файле `configure.ac`, перед запуском `./autogen.sh` закомментировать строки:

```
#AC_CHECK_LIB([crypto],[RAND_egd],[],[
#  AC_ARG_WITH([libressl],
#    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-libressl],[Build with system LibreSSL (default is no; DANGEROUS; NOT SUPPORTED)])],
#    [AC_MSG_WARN([Detected LibreSSL: This is NOT supported, and may break consensus compatibility!])],
#    [AC_MSG_ERROR([Detected LibreSSL: This is NOT supported, and may break consensus compatibility!])]
#  )
#])
```

Но и этого будет не достаточно для сборки даже *Dogecoin*, не то что отставших "вилок" типа *Infinitycoin* и т. п.

Но всё это прекрасно собирается на `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`. Можно поставить, на том же *Debian* - lxc контейнер.

```
$ dpkg -l libssl-dev
libssl-dev:amd64  1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10  amd64  Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
```

И в этой *устаревшей* версии присутствует пресловутый конструктор *BN_init()*

```
$ grep -n BN_init /usr/include/openssl/*
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:438:void BN_init(BIGNUM *);
```

Так что, если кто-то хочет сохранить на жёстком диске пару миллиончиков *Dogecoin* или *Infinitycoin*, можете смело ставить *Debian*, а на него lxc контенер с *Ubuntu*.